# Subdomain name not resolving

Tags: subdomain, plesk

I have created a subdomain using plesk panel 12.5 but when I type it's address the browser gives error err_name_not_resolved.
But when I used the preview option on plesk panel it shows the site. I want it to work with the subdomain address also.
I have checked other questions but they didn't helped.
Please help it's urgent.

Comment: If its urgent, provide the domain name and I can do an authorative lookup and advise if the problem relates to the authorative DNS or caching.

Comment: Domain name is : test.britishuniversityfair.co.uk

Comment: The main domain is working but subdomain doesn't.

Comment: I've queried a authorative nameserver for that subdomain and its not answering with a valid response.  This means that the problem is not to do with caching, and has to do either with the way Plesk is interacting with the nameservers, or, more likely, it is not authorative - ie you are updating the records in the wrong place.  (The nameservers are ns07.domaincontrol.com and ns08.domaincontrol.com )

Comment: After creating subdomain In the DNS settings I enabled the name servers which was shown there and all of the records like a cname etc. were created.

Comment: I thought that simply creating a subdomain and setting it's home path should be OK. But it didn't worked then in the after some searching around the web, I went to DNS settings and there were two DNS servers were shown so I enabled them. But it also didn't worked.

Comment: Certainly if you enabled nameservers in Plesk when there were not anything before that would seem wrong.   You should track down your domain registrar and ask them how to log in to your domain control panel and modify the servers there.

Comment: If I select the preview option then domain is shown. Here is the preview link. http://80.82.115.88/plesk-site-preview/test.britishuniversityfair.co.uk/80.82.115.88/

Comment: OK. So should I disable the nameservers in the plesk.

Comment: I have disabled the nameservers and it is set to defaults.

Comment: Still unsolved.

Comment: As already stated, you are updating the nameservers in the wrong place.  You need to find out who hosts your domain and change the DNS records in their control panel.  This has nothing to do with Plesk, and giving us a blow-by-blow of what you are doing in Plesk won't help your cause.

Comment: OK thanks now I understand I have to change DNS settings on registrar DNS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was resolved after I contacted the team who was managing the client's domain name and asked them to create a sub domain pointing to the server IP address.